# How to build a Linux app in Flutter from MacOS?

Tags: linux, flutter

Everything is in the title, but to give a bit more context :

- I am developing flutter apps for any platforms using a Macbook under MacOS 12.5
- I want to build my flutter app on a linux platform (typically Ubuntu Desktop and then on an embedded device)

Currently, i simply can't do `flutter build linux` on my MacOS because it is not a "linux host".

The first thing that came to my mind was to prepare a Linux VM where i should install Android studio, then build there...
I am actually looking for a better solution, using some scripts or CLI because this is how i will have to do for my embedded devices (without android studio) and i can't find any clear documentation about it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you only looking for a solution to use locally? If not then one way to do this would be to develop on your Macbook but build for Linux using a CI service, all of which provide an option to use Linux VMs.

Comment: Yes you are right that's actually a good idea. For now i am working on a VM using UTM at the moment on which a Debian 11 instance is running. The gitlab runners could do the job too but i am using github, i am not sure github has a CI service ?